# Selenium doesn't work every time with error element not attached

Tags: python, selenium, exception, youtube

I want to have informations on comments under youtube post including the term 'vidéo'.
However, sometimes I get an error "`element is not attached to the page document`" at the line marked with the comment : `# !!!!!!!!!!!!!`

```
from selenium import webdriver as wbd
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

attend = wbd.support.ui.WebDriverWait
avec = wbd.common.by.By
```

[...]

```
myElem = attend(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((avec.XPATH, '//*[@id="content-text"]')))
l_com = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="content-text"]')

com_commu = {}
terme = 'vidéo'
n = 0
délai = 5
for i in l_com :                   #!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    if terme in i.text :
        myElem = attend(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((avec.XPATH, '//*[@id="reply-button-end"]/ytd-button-renderer/a')))
        driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="reply-button-end"]/ytd-button-renderer/a')[n].click()
        myElem = attend(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((avec.XPATH, '//*[@id="body"]')))
        com_commu[i.text] = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="body"]')
        # driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/user/LeRiiiiiiiireJaune/community')
        driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
    else :
        print(f'Il n\'y a pas le terme "{terme}" dans le post : {i.text}')
    n += 1
```

if you have any idea of ​​the problem, thanks for the help ;)

Comment: If you get off the page you have to refind elements.

Comment: But why does it work sometimes ??

Comment: this might work if you never find "terme".